# Checking form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am quite new to JavaScript, and i have run into a problem. I have this form:

```
<form name="RegForm" method="get" action="formularTarget.html"
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
</form>
```

it uses text-inputs, which i want to check for correctness with the following script:

```
function validateForm() {
     var errorMsg = "";
     var errorFlag = false;
     var errorElem = null;

     if (checkBlankString(document.RegForm.elemVorname.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemVorname";
             errorMsg += "Pflichtfeld: Bitte Vornamen eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag = true;
     }

     if (checkBlankString(document.RegForm.elemNachname.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemNachname";
             errorMsg+="Pflichtfeld: Bitte Nachnamen eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag=true;
     }

     if (isNaN(document.RegForm.elemAlter.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemAlter";
             errorMsg+="Angegebenes Alter ist keine Zahl. " +
                       "Bitte als Alter eine Zahl " +
                       "zwischen 12 und 99 eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag=true;
     }

     else {
             if (document.RegForm.elemAlter.value < 12 || aForm.elemAlter.value > 99) {
                     errorElem = "elemAlter";
                     errorMsg+="Alter ausserhalb des Wertebereichs. " +
                               "Bitte ein Alter zwischen 12 und 99 eingeben.\n";
                     errorFlag=true;
             }
     }

     if (errorFlag==true){
             document.RegForm.elements[errorElem].focus();
             document.RegForm.elements[errorElem].select();
             alert(errorMsg);
             return false;
     } else {
             alert("Ihre Eingaben sind in Ordnung! \n" +
             "Drücken Sie OK, um sich zu registrieren.");
}
}
```

However, it does not work and just accepts any input. Where did i go wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to your form, and remove the onsubmit, like this:

```
<form name="RegForm" method="get" action="formularTarget.html">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm(this.form);" />
</form>
```

Then add the parameter to your validation function, and trigger the submit at the end of the function:

```
function validateForm(form) {
     var errorMsg = "";
     var errorFlag = false;
     var errorElem = null;

     if (checkBlankString(document.RegForm.elemVorname.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemVorname";
             errorMsg += "Pflichtfeld: Bitte Vornamen eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag = true;
     }

     if (checkBlankString(document.RegForm.elemNachname.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemNachname";
             errorMsg+="Pflichtfeld: Bitte Nachnamen eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag=true;
     }

     if (isNaN(document.RegForm.elemAlter.value)) {
             errorElem = "elemAlter";
             errorMsg+="Angegebenes Alter ist keine Zahl. " +
                       "Bitte als Alter eine Zahl " +
                       "zwischen 12 und 99 eingeben.\n";
             errorFlag=true;
     }

     else {
             if (document.RegForm.elemAlter.value < 12 || aForm.elemAlter.value > 99) {
                     errorElem = "elemAlter";
                     errorMsg+="Alter ausserhalb des Wertebereichs. " +
                               "Bitte ein Alter zwischen 12 und 99 eingeben.\n";
                     errorFlag=true;
             }
     }

     if (errorFlag==true){
             document.RegForm.elements[errorElem].focus();
             document.RegForm.elements[errorElem].select();
             alert(errorMsg);
             return false;
     } else {
             alert("Ihre Eingaben sind in Ordnung! \n" +
             "Drücken Sie OK, um sich zu registrieren.");
    }
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myValidate() {
var x = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
var y = document.forms["myform"]["country"].value;
var z = document.forms["myform"]["occupation"].value;
var a = document.forms["myform"]["status"].value;
var b = document.getElementById("nameErr");    
var c = document.getElementById("countryErr");
var d = document.getElementById("occupationErr");
var e = document.getElementById("statusErr");

if (!x || x.length==0) {
    b.innerHTML = "Name Must Be Filled Out";
    return false;
} else {
    b.innerHTML = "";
}

if (!y || y.length==0) {
    c.innerHTML = "Country Must Be Filled Out";
    return false;
} else {
    c.innerHTML = "";
}

if (!z || z.length==0) {
    d.innerHTML = "Occupation Must Be Filled Out";
    return false;
} else {
    d.innerHTML = "";
}

if (!a || a.length==0) {
    e.innerHTML = "Status Must Be Filled Out";
    return false;
} else {
    e.innerHTML = "";
}
return true;
```

}

this is the JavaScript

Name:

Country:

Occupation:

Status:

that the HTML